# After I approve a review how do I save it onto my website?

Tags: review

I have had my first sale and the customer purchased 5 products , then wrote a review about each item. I approved them in admin but it's not showing up on my website when you click on that particular item. Is there a way for me to decide what review can show up for each items? All new to me.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'review' you mean the standard review system Magento offers, if the reviews are approved they should appear on the product page. If you have some full page cache system, clear it for the pages that should contain reviews. if you have a multistore instance, make sure you check the pages in the store view where the reviews were posted. If you want them on all the store views you need to manually edit each review and assign it to all the store views.

**[EDIT]**
Based on the comment below...

You review shows up here: http://glamoroushairstyles.com.au/index.php/review/product/list/id/137.
It does not show up on your product page because your theme is constructed not to show reviews in the product view page. Not even a link to the reviews page with the number of reviews.

as a side note: there is something very wrong with your theme. It does not show the price of the product or the stock availability.

So I guess the problem is not what you described. the problem is your theme.

Comment: I approved the review in admin and its still not showing up. see the link for the item : http://glamoroushairstyles.com.au/index.php/wig-hair-brush.html  I am still trying to work everything out

Comment: @GlamorousHairstyles. See my update to the answer.

Comment: So back to my web developers again... You gave me my answer though I will look into it